# If T preserves the measure of A and B then it preserves the Measure of $A \cap B$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $T : (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda^1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda^1)$ be measurable. I claim that $T$ is measure preserving on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda^1)$ if and only if 
$$
\lambda^1(G) =\lambda^1(T^{-1}(G)) \ \ \ \ (\ast)
$$
for all open $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  We denote the collection of open sets by $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})$

The way I am trying to show this is by the following;

Clearly if $T$ is measure preserving then $(\ast)$ holds by definition.

Now suppose that $(\ast)$ holds, Then consider the system

$$
\Sigma = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}|\lambda^1(A) =\lambda^1(T^{-1}(A))\}
$$

Then clearly $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \Sigma$. So if we can show that $\Sigma$ is $\sigma$-algebra then we have
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})= \sigma(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R}))\subseteq \sigma(\Sigma) = \Sigma.
$$

Now showing that $\Sigma$ is a Dynkin System is easy enough, but now I am trying( and failing) to show that $\Sigma$ is closed under finite intersections. If I can show that $\Sigma$ is closed under finite intersections, then it will be $\sigma$-algebra as needed.

Cheers in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove directly that $\Sigma$ is a sigma algebra. The collection $\mathcal U$ of open sets is a $\pi-$ system contained in the Dynkin system $\Sigma$ and this implies that the sigma algebra generated by open sets is contained in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ref. p. 34 of Billingsley's Probability and Measure.

Comment: I am not familiar with pi-systems,  can you please explain how the pi-system being contained in the dynkin system gives us that the sigma algebra generated by open sets is in the dynkin system

Comment: I am using  a basic theorem about Dynkin systems which is proved on p. 34 of the book I have quoted, In fact, Dynkins systems are of no use without  this theorem, so I strongly suggest that you read that book..